# Cannot find Module "build" in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker

Im using Sveltekit to build a little Website now i want to Containerize it and run it on a small pc. I use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY /build /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD node build
```

But when I start the Container I get this Error:

```
2023-08-18 19:03:19 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
2023-08-18 19:03:19   throw err;
2023-08-18 19:03:19   ^
2023-08-18 19:03:19 
2023-08-18 19:03:19 Error: Cannot find module '/app/build'
2023-08-18 19:03:19     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
2023-08-18 19:03:19     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
2023-08-18 19:03:19     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
2023-08-18 19:03:19     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
2023-08-18 19:03:19   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-08-18 19:03:19   requireStack: []
2023-08-18 19:03:19 }
2023-08-18 19:03:19 
2023-08-18 19:03:19 Node.js v20.5.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't `COPY` the `build` folder, you copy the `src` (and everything else it needs to build the app) folder -- unless you build the image with built artifacts. Your *Dockerfile* should look something like this:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

Comment: But now i have the problem to load the website i added EXPOSE 3000 in the Dockerfile to expose port 3000 but if i run the Container and try to connect with my browser it cant reach the Website

Comment: When you run the container, you need to use `--publish` flag to forward the port `3000` from inside the container to the host machine: `docker run --publish 8080:3000 name-of-the-image`. Here we are forwarding port `3000` to `8080` on the host. So you should be able to see your app by visiting http://localhost:8080.